# error: C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to T

Tags: c++, c++17

I get this error both on VS2017 and g++, compiling with C++17 compliance. Can anyone explain?

```
template<typename T>
T doit(T&& arg) {
    int result{ arg * 2 };
    return result; // works
    // return arg; // works
    // return arg*2; // error: C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to T
}
int main() {
    int i {42};
    cout << doit(i) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have omitted the important information `[with T = int&]`. Temp r-value `arg*2` can't be assigned to non constant reference. Also `return result` does not work although looks like working, it's undefined behaviour, returns a reference to a local variable after its scope finished.

Answer (score 1):

`typename T` can be a reference type.

`std::remove_reference<T> doit(T&& arg) {` should solve this, since it forces return statement to copy, instead of potentially attempting to bind an r-value (`T&&`) to an l-value reference (`T&`).